# How to fill nulls by taking previous values of next column in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi all can you please help on this We have three columns lets say start time, end time and duration..
For suppose two rows have data in all three columns and duration will not be empty and start and end time columns in 3, 4, 5 rows   are  empty, in that case
I need to fill (3rd row)  start time by taking end time from 2nd row of end time and end time as sum of start time(3rd row) + duration (3rd row).. then i need to go for four row in same way to fill start time from 3rd row of end time and end time as sum of start time and duration of 4th rows..

Examples for start time is  timestamp  and end timetime aslo timestamp and duration is in seconds or microseconds

Can someone please help me how can i achieved that in pyspark

Comment: Please add an example dataframe input and desired output. Reading the text may lead to misinterpreting.

Comment: Also, you probably have some common ID for groups, please include the common ID too. I mean, what you described is probably one group of rows. There is probably another group of rows which will need the same algorithm. Just provide the column/-s with data which is needed to make such row groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark doesn't have function to calculate timestamp difference, therefore we need to calculate to get the difference time unit we want. below there is a link to how Pyspark is used.

http://sparkbyexamples.com/Pyspark

u will get an idea related to the problem.

Comment: Don't link to the example, provide the example in your post.